# Synchronize contacts between multiple devices

Tags: sync, google-contacts

Is there a possibility to manage contacts together?

Similar to the google calendar.

For clubs that would be very handy.

Comment: You mean you want a shared contact list where all the devices have access to the list?

Comment: Exactly, it would be best if the contacts can also be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Exchange Server or Office 365.

Exchange Server maintains the e-mail messages, contacts, and calendar information, so the data can be accessed from pretty much anywhere and any device.

Laptops can connect to Exchange over any Internet connection, and most smartphones and tablets can stay synced using Exchange Active Sync.

For example... BlackBerry smartphones and tablets use Blackberry Exchange Server rather than Exchange Active Sync to accomplish the same goal.

source : http://www.pcworld.com/article/228698/how_to_sync_your_data_across_all_platforms_pc_tablet_smartphone.html

Comment: Thanks. Are there also free, preferably browserbased, alternatives? 
I only need a part of the functions contained in MS Exchange.

Comment: I think Kopano or G Suits are good alternatives to MS Exchange.

Comment: @user220007 also Kerio Connect is very good.

Answer (score 0):

you must the google account if you have an android device or microsoft account if is windows device